# InverseSeries producing unacceptable results

Tags: series-expansion

I am attempting to invert an expression numerically using `Series` and `InverseSeries`.

For example, consider the expression

```
Jx = (2 Sqrt[Ex])/Pi EllipticE[u1/Ex];
```

To do so I try

```
Series[Jx, {Ex, ∞, 5}]
InverseSeries[Series[Jx, {Ex, ∞, 5}]]
```

But this gives an obviously false result. To see that it's false, it's easier to just compare these two:

```
Series[Jx, {Ex, ∞, 5}]
InverseSeries[InverseSeries[Series[Jx, {Ex, ∞, 5}]]]
```

which gives an entirely different series. Inverting the series twice should give the same thing back.

My first thought was that `InverseSeries` expands around 0, while I'm trying to expand around `∞`. But the same issue can be seen by comparing two outputs where we expand around 0, but the first term is infinite at 0:

```
3 x^(-1/2) + 5 x^(1/2) + 12 x^(3/2) + O[x]^(5/2)
InverseSeries[InverseSeries[3 x^(-1/2) + 5 x^(1/2) + 12 x^(3/2) + O[x]^(5/2)]]
```

There removing the first term would cause the two lines to give the same result.

My second thought was that I could get around this by defining the inverse `ExI = 1/Ex` and expand around 0 using that, but this didn't change anything.

So I have these questions:

- Is `InverseSeries` really limited in the ways I describe? (Always inverts around 0, can't deal with infinite first term)
- How can I invert my expression, either with or without `InverseSeries`?

Comment: Perhaps `Sqrt[1/ExI] InverseSeries[1/Sqrt[1/ExI] Series[Jx /. Ex -> 1/ExI, {ExI, 0, 5}]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`InverseSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseSeries) has an issue here, but we can manipulate it's output to provide the correct series. Here is your expression (modified slightly):

```
J[u_, x_] := (2 Sqrt[x])/Pi EllipticE[u/x]
```

Now, the series expansion of `J`:

```
ser = Series[J[u, x], {x, Infinity, 5}];
ser //TeXForm
```

> $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{4} u \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}-\frac{3}{64} u^2
>    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}-\frac{5}{256} u^3
>    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{5/2}-\frac{175 u^4
>    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{7/2}}{16384}-\frac{441 u^5
>    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{9/2}}{65536}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{11/2}\right)$

Next, the output of [`InverseSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseSeries):

```
inv = InverseSeries[ser];
inv //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{u}{2}+\frac{u^2 x^2}{32}+\frac{5 u^4 x^6}{8192}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$

The problem with this output is that the series is being expanded around $x=0$ and not $x=\infty$. Let's rewrite it so that it is in the expected form:

```
new = Series[Normal[inv] /. x->1/y, {y, Infinity, 10}];
new //TeXForm
```

> $y^2+\frac{u}{2}+\frac{u^2}{32 y^2}+\frac{5 u^4}{8192
>    y^6}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)^{11}\right)$

I think this is the correct inverse series. Let's turn this into a function, and see if it is indeed the inverse of `J`:

```
IJ[u_, y_] := Evaluate[Normal[new]]
```

Here are a couple examples:

```
J[2, 1.2`20*^10]
IJ[2, J[2, 1.2`20*^10]]

J[20, 1.3`20*^20]
IJ[20, J[20, 1.3`20*^20]]
```

> 109544.51149646886805
>
> 1.2000000000000000000*10^10
>
> 1.1401754250991379791*10^10
>
> 1.3000000000000000000*10^20

So, the above evidence supports the fact that the function `IJ` is the inverse of `J`, and hence `new` is the inverse series of the series of `J`.

Comment: This does seem to work, and I can verify the first three terms with pencil and paper. Thanks! However I don't entirely understand why that worked. My understanding is that expanding around `x=0` and `x=inf` are distinctly different things. Yet somehow you took the former, replaced `x->1/y`, expanded around `y=inf` (which is the same as `x=0`) and that worked? Can you clarify the reasoning for me?

Comment: P.S. Happy to learn about `Normal`